# Stop Activity Indicator while no row in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am using the code below to retrieve data from Url via PHP file, the tableview controller will start the Activity Indicator. What I am trying to do is to stop the indicator As soon as there are no data has been loaded to the tableview.

Her is the code;

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/MyWebSite/ChoseMyLike.php?userName=%@", myString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!data) {
            NSLog(@"connection error: %@", error);

            return;
        }

        NSError *parseError;
        NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];
        if (!json) {
            NSLog(@"JSON Parsing error: %@", parseError);
            NSLog(@"data = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

            return;
        }

        NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
            NSString *cQasidaName = json[i][@"qasidaName"];
            NSString *cQasidaShaerName = json[i][@"qasidaShaerName"];
            NSString *cQasidaBody = json[i][@"qasidaBody"];
            NSString *cQasidaDate = json[i][@"myDate"];
            NSString *cQasidaTime = json[i][@"myTime"];
            NSString *cQasidaRate = json[i][@"myRate"];
            NSString *cQasidaId = json[i][@"qasidaId"];
            NSString *cQasidaUserName = json[i][@"userName"];
            NSString *cTheUserId = json[i][@"theUserId"];
            NSString *cTheUserNameArabic = json[i][@"userNameArabic"];

            [results addObject:[[ListOfObjects alloc] initWithQasidaName: (NSString *) cQasidaName andQasidaShaerName: (NSString *) cQasidaShaerName andQasidaBody: (NSString *) cQasidaBody andQasidaDate: (NSString *) cQasidaDate andQasidaTime: (NSString *) cQasidaTime andQasidaRate: (NSString *)cQasidaRate andQasidaId:cQasidaId andQasidaUserName:cQasidaUserName andTheUserId:cTheUserId andTheUserNameArabic:cTheUserNameArabic]];



        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.listArray = results;


            [self.tableView reloadData];

            [spinner stopAnimating];




        });
                          }];


    [task resume];



}
```

At the moment the indicator is not stopping. What do I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: "As soon as there are no data has been loaded to the tableview."  That's not clear.  Also where is `spinner` initialized?  Could it be `nil`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean if there is no data, The Url request return nothing. at that stage i want to stop the indicator

Comment: In other way, The table is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `[spinner stopAnimating];` for all return paths:

```
if (!data) {
    NSLog(@"connection error: %@", error);
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    return;
}
```

and

```
if (!json) {
    NSLog(@"JSON Parsing error: %@", parseError);
    NSLog(@"data = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    [spinner stopAnimating];    
    return;
}
```

Note: it's much easier to have a single `return` statement and then you can always call `[spinner stopAnimating];` at the end of the method... consider restructuring your code.

Comment: I did change my code by adding [spinner stopAnimating] but still have the same problem

Comment: @Ahmed.S.Alkaabi I would restructure your code.  You want `if (loaded) { if (gotdata) { process_data(); } }  [spinner stopAnimating]; return;`.